# Raspberry Pi Chromium can't find webpage on boot

Tags: linux, chromium, raspberry-pi

We have a raspberry pi in our office which boots directly into the browser using a line in the .profile file as follows

```
xinit /usr/bin/chromium --kiosk --incognito internalsite.internal.com
```

And a login bypass by changing the following line in the /etc/inittab file

change

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1
```

to

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

This works fine apart from the fact that when it boots up it displays a page can not be found message.... If we press f5 it loads the page correctly....

I have setup the exact same thing on a pi in my house and it works fine and the browser boots up and displays the specified web page perfectly.

The site is internal so does not go through a proxy.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Perhaps asking the question here, might help; http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the network driver hasn't finished connecting yet, before the .profile script starts. Change the script to check that a valid IP has been obtained before sending the web request.

Comment: how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @coolblue2000 the easiest way would probably be to edit the `.profile` and add `sleep 10` before the xinit line to make it wait for 10 seconds before executing xinit. You can set the sleep length to whatever suits your needs.

Comment: Brilliant, I used sleep 10 which did not work, but sleep 30 works fine! Thank you